# Trouble populating UITableView with a CustomCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

I'm trying to make a UITableView with each cell consisting of a question and several buttons displayed underneath said question for the user may choose one to answer.

When I am on my initial page and I select the button 'take test' it segues to the next screen where my UITableView is but then crashes.

I set up a CustomCell class with an IBOutlet to a UITextView and seven UIButtons. I linked the UITextView and UIButtons to their appropriate variables.  Here is some code to show you how I am populating each cell. I don't understand the errors in my screenshot. If anyone could help me out with what I am doing wrong I would greatly appreciate it. Let me know if there is anymore information I can provide.

TestViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Questions.h"
#import "CustomCell.h"

@interface TestViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *instructions;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *results;
//@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet *question;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Questions *survey;

-(IBAction)backPressed:(id)sender;
@end
```

TestViewController.m

```
#import "TestViewController.h"

@interface TestViewController ()

@end

@implementation TestViewController {
    NSDictionary *allQuestions;
}

@synthesize survey;
@synthesize results;
@synthesize instructions;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"Personality Test";
    survey = [[Questions alloc] init];

    // set up question array
    survey.questions = @[@"1. You find it difficult to introduce yourself to other people",
                        @"2. You often get so lost in thoughts that you ignore or forget your surroundings",
                        // many more.....
                       ];

    // set up answers array
    // -1 means unanswered
    // 0 means neutral
    // 1 means weakly agree or weakly disagree
    // 2 means agree or disagree
    // 3 means strongly agree or strongly disagree
    survey.answers = @[[NSNumber numberWithInt:-1],
                       [NSNumber numberWithInt:-1],
                       // many more.....
                      ];

    // set up dictionary of question/answer relationship
    allQuestions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:survey.questions forKeys:survey.answers];

    //
    // depending on what question is asked based on categories
    // each question fits into one of the 5:
    // 1. Mind: Introvert or Extravert
    // 2. Energy: Observant or Intuitive
    // 3. Nature: Thinking or Feeling
    // 4. Tactics: Judging or Prospecting
    // 5. Identity: Assertive or Turbulent
    // Each array spot will hold one of the two words on the right

    // set up types array
    survey.types = @[@"neutral",
                     @"neutral",
                    // many more.....
                   ];

    NSString *instr = @"Things to know:\n1. Takes less than 12 minutes.\n2. Answer honestly, even if you don't like the answer. \n3. Try not to leave any 'neutral' answers ";
    //UIFont *instrFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12];
    //CGSize textviewSize = [instr sizeWithFont:instrFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(300, CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    //instructions = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 30, 300, 100)];
    instructions.text = instr;
    //[self.view addSubview:instructions];

    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(backPressed:)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [survey.questions count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"QuestionCell";

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    /*
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    */

    NSString *que = (NSString *)[survey.questions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //UITextView *textView = (UITextView *)[cell viewWithTag: 100];
    cell.textView = (UITextView *)[cell viewWithTag: 100];
    cell.textView.text = que;

    return cell;
}
```

Here are two screenshots: one of my UITableView in the StoryBoard and the other is an image of my my errors.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Does your custom cell use an XIB? Also, what exactly isn't working?

Comment: No it doesn't. I updated my code to show you I set up an NSDictionary to hold 2 arrays: one questions and the other the answer.

Comment: My apologies. I posted the question without explaining everything. I have it updated now though. The app crashes after I click a button from my main VC to the VC with my UITableView

Comment: The error says that you're not returning a cell from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.  Check that the reuse identifier is correct in your custom cell inside the storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to give the cell a reuse identifier of "QuestionCell" in the storyboard.  You must also register the custom class for that identifier with the table view. (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:)).

Somewhere at or after viewDidLoad...

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[CustomCell self]
       forCellReuseIdentifier:@"QuestionCell"];
```

Comment: This helped because now I can go to the next page but my table still isn't being populated. In the iOS simulator it is blank but I can still scroll through the table

Comment: I registered my custom class in the beginning of viewDidLoad

Comment: Glad it helped.  I think what's happening is that you're on to the next problem... quite likely something going wring configuring the cell.  In `cellForRowAtIIndexPath` try logging the string called `que` and try logging `cell.textView`.  On the latter, be sure the textView's frame falls within the cell's frame (log the cell, too).

Comment: I think it might be that the textView frame doesn't fall within the cell's frame. It looks tricky for me in the StoryBoard view but the textView bordered look like they are inside the cells frame. I will upload a better screenshot for you

Comment: I logged the que and it has the appropriate question. I logged cell and it gave me some information about it. here's an example: 2015-12-06 18:37:21.297 final_project[42773:7149897] Cell Value: <CustomCell: 0x7f93d200a800; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 44); layer = <CALayer: 0x7f93d0704d00>>

Comment: My textView's width is 550 and the with of my cell is 560. The buttons are also within the frame of my cell. Everything has constraints so they aren't moving. I don't know how else to determine if the textView's frame is within the cell's frame

Comment: Looks like your cell width is 320... see in your last comment where it says  "frame = (0 0; 320 44);"  That should be fine.  When you log the textView, what is its origin?  Also try this for fun:  `cell.textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];` does anything turn red?  If not, we're onto something with the frames.

Comment: When I log the textView, it says '2015-12-06 19:01:42.025 final_project[43053:7179964] TextVIew Value: (null)'

Comment: The background color does not change to red as well

Comment: So the frame is not the actual x,y dimensions of the cell? when i log the textView, should that be giving me the frame dimensions as well?

Comment: null means cell.textView is not initialized.  Is there an IBOutlet on the custom cell for the textView?